# Uploading local gradle project to GitHub repository

Tags: java, eclipse, github, libgdx

I'm fairly new to github so this might be a very simple issue. I have been working on a basic game using libGDX. I used the gdx setup tool to create the gradle project and I have since been developing locally. All I wanted was to upload my code to github so I could share code more easily, but I have never done so through eclipse.

I went on github and created a new repository. Then I cloned the repository and attempted to commit and push my project. However, the gdx setup tool actually created three projects: core, desktop, and a gradle project. I wasn't sure what to do so I pushed each project independently to the repository. core and desktop only contained .project. The gradle project contained all the class files that were originally within core and desktop, so I deleted core and desktop from the repository.

Now when I import the repository into eclipse, all my class files are there and there are no errors but run as shows that there are no applications to run my code. How can I somehow salvage this code so that I can run it and then properly upload it to a github repository?

Comment: May help: https://help.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-source-code-to-github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I talk about directories below, I mean the ones in your file system, not the way projects are arranged in the Project Explorer view in Eclipse.

You should create a single repository using the directory that contains all the modules (`core`, `desktop`, etc.). Use `git init` from the command line in your base directory. Then do your initial commit of all your files. Keep your command line window open.

Then create a new repository on Github. **Don't** select to initialize it with a README file. On the next screen, in the section "**…or push an existing repository from the command line**" it will have code you can copy and paste into your command line window to do your initial push to Github and set the Github repo as the remote `origin` that is tracked.

It is probably easiest if you delete the Github repo and local repo(s) you already created and start over. You can delete the local repos by deleting the `.git` directory.

Comment: I followed those steps and successfully uploaded my code to GitHub, and now I'm trying to actually import the code back into eclipse so that it can be accessed on any computer. I cloned the repository with GitHub Desktop, but when I import from the cloned file, it attempts to merge everything into one project even though the repository is composed of the three modules I mentioned earlier. How can I import the repo so that it appears just like it did before I uploaded it to GitHub

Comment: Can you share a link to the repo? I haven't used Eclipse with Gradle in several years, so I'm not sure about that side of it. But maybe there's something wrong with your repo.

Comment: I think your repo is private.

Comment: Sorry about that, should be public now

Comment: That all looks correct. In IntelliJ, you would clone the project and open the `build.gradle` file from the root directory and it imports as a new project. I don't remember how this works in Eclipse, sorry. Eclipse has the notion of a workspace with multiple projects in it, and I don't know how it handles multiple gradle projects in a single workspace, if that's even possible.

Comment: I do remember that working with Gradle was so counter-intuitive in Eclipse that that was the primary reason I switched to using IntelliJ as my primary IDE.